# Adding rowspan to a column with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I have a table generated by ajax. After the table is created, i'd like to add a rowspan to a specific column. I've used

```
$('#col_input').attr('rowspan', '2');
```

but the result seems not right. Even if the rowspan is added the value of the column is combined like this.

```
A   B     C
1         3
1   222   3
1         3
```

How can I change it like this.

```
A   B     C
1         3
1   2     3
1         3
```

Here's my ajax success script that generate the table

```
success: function(response)
{
    var tableData,t1,t2,t3;

    $.each(response, function(index, data) {

        t1  = "<tr><td>1</td>";
        t2  = "<td id='col_input'><input type='text' id='val_a' value='2' /></td>";
        t3  = "<td>3</td></tr>";

        tableData += t1+t2+t3;
        $('#tbl_add tbody tr').remove();
        $('#tbl_add tbody').append(tableData);
    });

     $('#col_input').attr('rowspan', '2'); 
}
```

and my html if needed

```
<table id="tbl_add">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>A</strong></td>
            <td><strong>B</strong></td>
            <td><strong>C</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

nb: the value of the rowspan is the number of data generated by ajax

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the expected result , use index in .each() function to control the additional row on every loop and for tesing used below response json

```
 response = [{
   "val_a": "1",
   "rowspan":"2"
 }, {
   "val_a": "2"
 }]
 var tableData, t1, t2, t3;

 $.each(response, function(index, data) {

   t1 = "<tr><td>1</td>";
   if (index == 0) {
console.log(data.rowspan)
     t2 = "<td id='col_input' rowspan='"+data.rowspan+"'><input type='text' id='val_a' value='2' /></td>";
   }
   t3 = "<td>3</td></tr>";
   if (index == 0) {
     tableData += t1 + t2 + t3;
   } else {
     tableData += t1 + t3;
   }
   $('#tbl_add tbody tr').remove();
   $('#tbl_add tbody').append(tableData);
 });

 //$('#col_input').attr('rowspan', '2');
```

Commentd out the assigning rowspan and assigned checking index and value from the response JSON as mentioned in the post

Codepen URL-http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/XKjEzj

Hope this works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

While iterating over the response object, you are creating multiple TDs with **id='col_input'**.

Using:

```
$('#col_input').attr('rowspan', '2');
```

will only select the first TD with ID "rowspan".

Use classes instead, e.g.

```
$('.col_input').attr('rowspan', '2');
```